# Can we upload documents from Flex to Google app engine blobstore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, flex4

I am working in Flex with Java.  I have a question about Flex application running in Google app engine.  Can we upload documents from a Flex client to Google app. engine blobstore?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

If you have written server side code using Java (or Python), and using HTTP for uploading files to server. I mean that there is need to be an server side code, because you can't access database directly from Flex.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I have an example code that uses jsp to upload documents into blobstore.In the jsp file they used blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") to create blobstore upload url. In the servlet file they used BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService(); to get the information.Is there anyway to use Blobstore service in flex side or do i need to find another way to upload from flex

Comment: It depends on. First: you can upload without any blobstore, but you can't store entity more that 1Mb long. Blobstore is used for storing large files. At this case you need blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload"), and then upload your files into this url. btw, don't forget to store somewhere link to this blob (BlobKey)

Answer (score 0):

If you can create and submit multipart forms in Flex, you can upload to the blobstore. From Flex's point of view, there is no difference between uploading files to the blobstore and uploading them anywhere else. You do not access the blobstore in Flex - you just upload to a URL provided by your server-side code.

If you've tried this and are having specific problems, you should update your post with details.